# How handle resources likes images, *.css with Spring Mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, resources, static

I've a problem with handle static resources.
It's my web-app
WebAppRoot
-resources
 -css
  -style.css
 -imahes
-jsp
 -template.jsp
 -secure
  -template_secure.jsp
so
myLocation=resources

How can I handle resource in a central way, for example I put location in a variable and
use this in tag

I tried with  but I don't understand how have to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 3.0.4 or later, you can use the [< mvc:resources ...>](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) element in your application configuration, and you will not need to create a `Controller` to handle static content for you.

It is as simple as specifying the location of your static content, and the path from which to access them:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

This uses the mvc namespace found http://static.springsource.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd.